# Logging in .NET Core without DI?

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

It seems that Microsoft are really trying to shove DI down your throat with .NET Core, and I'm not sure why, but frankly my console app is small and simple and I just don't want to build a whole DI container just to do some simple logging.  How can I do logging in .NET Core without using DI?  Everything I've read assumed you're going to use .NET Core's built-in logging architecture which obviously requires DI, but there must be a way to just do it without DI using a static variable on the class?

Comment: I like their Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) library myself, which doesn't require DI.

Comment: Simple Injector author have written a whole blog post on why it's wrong to do this [here](https://blog.simpleinjector.org/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/). So it's a very good question why Microsoft is pushing this DI with everything instead of making everything DI friendly, so that any container can be used

Comment: var logger = new Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerFactory().CreateLogger<T>();

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As per Ilyas and bokibegs comments in Scotts answer here is the currently working code for .NET 5.0:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

```cs
var factory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => {
    builder.AddConsole();
});

var logger = factory.CreateLogger<T>();
```

This requires the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` nuget packages.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do it yourself you will need to instantiate a [LoggerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerfactory) instance somewhere and configure what providers you want. Then you just need to call [CreateLogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerfactory.createlogger?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LoggerFactory_CreateLogger_System_String_) to create a instance or use `new Logger<T>(ILoggerFactory)` to create a logger.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

static class MyLogger {

    public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory {get;}

    static MyLogger() {
        LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
        LoggerFactory.AddConsole();
    }
}

public MyClass {
    private readonly ILogger _logger = new Logger<MyClass>(MyLogger.LoggerFactory);
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is now obsolete in the latest .Net Core in favor of ILoggingBuilder extensions that is actually hard coupled with DI again...

Comment: Relevant link for whatever's worth: [Use ILogger without dependency injection](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/615)

Answer (score 7):

What I ended up doing was using NLog but rather than using their .NET Core DI extensions, I just included the [main NLog NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog), manually creating my own `NLog.config` file, and followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#configure-nlog-targets-for-output) to `GetCurrentClassLogger()`, creating that as a static member of my class, then directly used that for logging.  This is quite a simple setup and has no need for DI.  NLog should probably document it better.

Comment: I've been using NLog professionally for 6 years.  It's been amazingly dependable and easy to use.

Comment: You can also integrate them so that Nlog provides the loggers for DI ILoggers

Answer (score 1):

**Complete example** using .NET Core 6 and NLog 4.7.

1. Run `dotnet new console`
2. Run `dotnet add package NLog`
3. Create a new text file named `NLog.config`<sup>1</sup>.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
        <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

4. Add the `NLog.config` file to your project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="NLog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.13" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

5. Edit the Program.cs file as follows:

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info("Program started.");
logger.Info("Program completed.");
```

6. Run `dotnet run`.

**Expected Output**

```
> dotnet run
2022-02-08 17:23:37.0430|INFO|Program|Program started.
2022-02-08 17:23:37.0924|INFO|Program|Program completed.
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#configure-nlog-targets-for-output</sup>